# WPF: Listbox or menu will not close on click (inside a Telerik Splitbutton)

Tags: wpf, telerik

I have the split button defined as below (in a control template). When the user selects a menu item, I expect the menu to close. I dont know if it's in the SplitButton or Menu that is not closing. It have tried with a ListBox as well, instead of a menu and got the same result.

`IsSplitButtonOpen` and all the other bound properties are defined in the viewmodel. IsSplitButtonOpen is set to false in the event handler of the command.

```html
<telerik:RadSplitButton Content="New Search"  
                        Height="22"  
                        Visibility="{TemplateBinding AddButtonVisibility}" 
                        AutoOpenDelay="0:0:0.5"
                        IsOpen="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadTabbedWindow}}, Path=DataContext.IsSplitButtonOpen}" 
                        Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadTabbedWindow}}, Path=DataContext.ShowSearchCommand}" 
                        CommandParameter="SearchAccountsView">

                                   

    <telerik:RadSplitButton.DropDownContent>
        <telerik:RadMenu Orientation="Vertical"                                                               
                            ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadTabbedWindow}}, Path=DataContext.NewTabListItems}" >
            <telerik:RadMenu.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="{Binding Text}"  
                                Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadTabbedWindow}}, Path=DataContext.ShowSearchCommand}" 
                                CommandParameter="{Binding ViewName}" 
                                />
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:RadMenu.ItemTemplate>
        </telerik:RadMenu>
    </telerik:RadSplitButton.DropDownContent> 
</telerik:RadSplitButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, try to use *CloseOnPopupMouseLeftButtonUp* property and set it to *True*. Both RadSplitButton and RadDropDownButton have that property. You can even refuse *IsOpen* property if it has only one purpose.